# Is there any command to check what plugins I am using in my RoR application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Can I use any command to check if my application is using any plugins or not?

Comment: The answer you have accepted is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Corrected answer

Just look in the `vendor/plugins` directory. (If you don't have a `vendor` directory, you're not using any plugins).

### INCORRECT ANSWER

You want to run this from inside the main directory of your Rails app:

```
./script/plugin list
```

You can also get lots of nifty info from:

```
./script/plugin --help
```

Comment: That lists available plugins, not the ones that an application is actually using.

Comment: It looks like "script/plugin sources" might do it.

Comment: No, that lists configured plugin repositories i.e. where Rails looks when you install a plugin. There is no `script/plugin` command to list the plugins that an application is using. You just have to look under `vendor/plugins`.